# Reason for jQuery Cycle function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was testing out a slider I built on a local connection, and it worked great, but then when I tried to upload it to my server, it just stacks the images on top of one another. What are some reasons as to why it would work locally, but not when I take it live?

```
                <html>
                    <head>
                       <title>Test</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet"; type="text/css"; href="Snoopz2.css";/>
                          <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                                    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>

                    </head>
                         <body>

                            <script type="text/javascript">

                               $(document).ready(function() {
                                 $('.slideshow') .cycle({
                                      fx: 'scrollLeft', 
                                      delay:  -2000,
                                      next:   '.button2', 
                                      prev:   '.button1',
                                      pause:   1

                                    });

                                 });
                        </script>

                            <div class="slideshow">

                            <div class="slide1">
                                <img src="/Images2/Cavs.jpg" />

                            </div><!--/slide-->

                            <div class="slide2">
                                <img src="/Images2/tiger.jpg" />


                            </div><!--/slide-->

                            <div class="slide3">
                                <img src="/Images2/LandonDonovan.jpg" />

                            </div><!--/slide-->

                        </div>




                    </body>
               </html>
```

here is the CSS:

```
           .slideshow  {
              width:600px;
              height:257px;
              margin:0;
              padding:0;
              position:relative;
              overflow:hidden;
             }

           .slideshow {
             margin:0;
             padding:0;
             width:600px; 
             height:257px;
             float:left;
             position:relative;
           }
```

Website that I'm trying to test this on: http://thesnoopz.com/AASliderTest.html

Comment: Do you see any errors in the dev tools console?

Comment: just checked, it said it failed to load `//cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js` which it's obvious now that the failed load is the problem, but why would this work locally and not when it's live?

Comment: Because the server probably isn't logged in or doesn't have access to it via keys / id. If I try to access it, I get: <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>[REQUEST ID WAS HERE]</RequestId><HostId>[HOST ID WAS HERE]</HostId></Error>

Comment: I also get what @kkirsche gets -- an Access Denied error. Try the raw public GitHub URL instead: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/malsup/cycle/master/jquery.cycle.all.js

Comment: hmm. I guess I need to download the plugging from the site then. Time to figure out how to do that. lol I'm still pretty new to all this.

Comment: @ajp15243 that didn't work, in fact when I used that, it just deleted all the images off the page lol.

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 Step 1: Are there errors in the console? :)

Comment: @ajp15243 just the one mentioned above declaring failure to load

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 That error still shows even after switching to the GitHub URL I provided??

Comment: @ajp15243 oh sorry, I misunderstood your question. After trying it again, the images show back up ( Still stacked) and the console no longer shows the failure to load error, but now shows `[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('.slideshow') .cycle')
 (anonymous function) (AASliderTest.html, line 23)
 resolveWith (jquery.min.js, line 16)
 ready (jquery.min.js, line 16)
 y (jquery.min.js, line 16)`

Comment: Looks like the `cycle` plugin isn't being added to jQuery for some reason. See what `$().cycle` returns (it should print out a function if it's working). Are you sure you need to use such an old version (1.5) of jQuery? The 1.x branch is on 1.11.x at this point -- 1.5 is very old.

Comment: @ajp15243 I just used the version they link to on w3schools.com. Since i'm new to all this, I was just went with what they told me lol.

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 Wow, W3Schools is still linking to 1.5? You should know that [W3Schools isn't always reliable or up-to-date](http://bit.ly/KQcoyZ), and have no affiliation with the W3C (one of the officiating web standards groups). Instead, use the [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](http://mzl.la/18PfQp3), the [W3C wiki](http://bit.ly/1pGJqSm), the [official HTML5 spec docs](http://bit.ly/P8QiKx) (warning, heavy reading), the [jQuery Learning Center](http://bit.ly/1B1h37o), and the [Microsoft Developer Network (MSDN)](http://bit.ly/1uwJc1D) (for IE).

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 I'll typically include the network name plus my search criteria in Google in order to get to the relevant page on the site, otherwise it can be hard to navigate to.

Comment: Actually I take that back, I went back and looked at what I had been using on some other files, and the 1.5 version was actually something i copy and pasted and forgot to delete. The code I was using locally actually had reference to both 1.5 and 1.11 by accident. Still worked though and thats why I didn't notice :).

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 So remove 1.5 and keep 1.11. Is it still broken?

Comment: @ajp15243 still broken, I just don't know what to do. I've tried everything I can think of and I either get a blank page with no error messages in the log, or image stacking and a 403 forbidden message in the log.

Comment: @ajp15243 any other suggestions?

Comment: I think posting all of your code, and possibly a link to your page on your server. Having others try to reproduce it is probably the best next step.

Comment: alright... give me just a second and I will update the original post.

Comment: @ajp15243 post has been update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the cycle to work by placing the

```
     <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
```

in the `<body>` instead of the `<head>`

unfortunately I'm getting some really weird issues where it only shows up in a small box at the top of screen

http://thesnoopz.com/AASliderTest.html